# Saving text file from code

Tags: file, text, notepad++, pascal

I have made this code:

```
Program Pzim ;
   var
     i:integer;
     vect:array[1..1001] of integer;
Begin
     i:=1;
     for i:= 1 to 999 do
     vect[i]:=i+1;
     for i:= 1 to 999 do
     writeln (vect[i]);
   readln;
End.
```

The program print a number sequence.
I want to save in a text file what is printed.

it could be made using the Pascal yet or even using another source? Notepad++ maybe?

Comment: I can't tell you why it didn't work, because I can't see what you tried. See my answer below.

Comment: For your own sake, indent your code better. This is a small piece of code, @Joás, but when code grows indentation is a MUST DO. Better to create the habit now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @EddeAlmeida. I am gonna to save that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can write to a text file in Pascal.

```
Program Pascal ;

var
  i:integer;
  vect:array[1..1001] of integer;
  Myfile: text;

begin
  i:=1;
  for i:= 1 to 999 do
    vect[i]:=i+1;

  Assign(Myfile, 'Myfile.txt');
  Rewrite(MyFile);

  for i:= 1 to 999 do
  begin
    WriteLn (vect[i]);
    WriteLn(Myfile, vect[i]);
  end;
  Close(Myfile);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: it says:
"It was not found the kind TextFile statement"
What it supposed to be?

Comment: Hey I got Fix!
Thanks. Just could you change in your answer the var "textfile" to "text".
Maybe it was because of the version of pascal.

Comment: Looks like you already did. :-) `TextFile` may be a Borland Pascal (or even Delphi) thing. I haven't used standard Pascal since the 1980's.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on which version of Pascal you are using, but in many versions this will work.

In the `var` section, add

```
f : textfile;  // f can be any variable name
```

After the `vect[i]:=i+1` line, insert

```
assign( f, 'c:\path\filename.txt'; // where path and filename are what you want.

rewrite( f);
```

then change the write statement to `writeln( f, ...)` where `f` is the name used above.  And before the end statement, insert `closefile( f);` (or `close(f)` in some versions).

Comment: I made what you said @Jud Mc Cranie but now it says: " the chain must be closed before the end of the program."